# How do I get Terminator to start up with my custom layout?

Tags: terminator

Terminator is very powerful at organizing several computers or servers due to the split window and group all function. But here's the deal: I created my own Layout and would appreciate it to load at startup of terminator. Is that possible?

Comment: Can you post your `~/.config/terminator/config`, or at least everything below `[layouts]`?

Comment: Hi... There is no Folder ~/.config/terminator.

Comment: If you have a running command in your layout, terminator need a few seconds for drawing layout. Add a line as `sleep 1` in your shell script.

Comment: open config file `~/.config/terminator/config` and edit `command = cd /some/folder; bash`. then save it and reopen the terminator.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There is a very easy way to accomplish this:

- **Open** Terminator
- Right click -> **Preferences**
- In the **Layouts** tab (to the right of the **Profiles** tab), edit the default one, you will see that it says ***Window*** | **window0** and ***Terminal*** | **child1**.
- For the ***Terminal*** | **child1**, you can set: a **Profile** (to choose from the installed ones), a **Default command**, and a **Working directory**.
- **Set** it/them to whatever you like, **close**, **reopen** again...
- ... and **voilá**!

Hope this helped!

Comment: Important: Follow these steps *exactly* and it works. Bizarrely, if you click "Save" after setting a Custom command and/or Working directory, it won't work. Clicking Save seems to clear anything you entered for Custom command and Working directory.

Comment: This does not even answer the question. The question is about changing the default layout, not changing the profile for specific terminals in a layout.

Comment: I've flagged it as it does not answer the question even though it is marked as such. I think for the sake of a strong community it is vital that the answer, even if it helps the original questioner, also helps the community. This answer does not.

Comment: The question is about setting user-preferred layout as default during startup. This is not the solution!

Answer (score 214):

1. After setting up your layout, right-click on any terminal background and choose **Preferences** → **Layouts** tab and click on **Add** button.
2. Give it a name and hit **Close**.
3. This should create the mentioned `~/.config/terminator/config` file.
4. Now you can start terminator using the saved layout using: `terminator -l yourLayout` (replace *yourLayout* with whatever you chose on step 2).
5. **(optional)** Edit the `~/.config/terminator/config` file so that where it says `[layouts]` and nested below it `[[yourLayout]]`, rename *yourLayout* to *default* and remove/rename the previous *default* layout. Now, when Terminator starts without any parameters, it will load your custom `[[default]]` layout!
6. **(optional)** Edit the `[[[terminalx]]]/ command = a custom command;bash` eg: `command = ssh user@IP;bash` (ending with bash) for each terminal, so that it will run your custom command during startup!!

Comment: I guess there is no way to make it remember also the paths where each window is when being saved?

Comment: The flags suggested by @Patrick on his [answer below](http://askubuntu.com/a/431249/56496) solves the layout issues on my first commend.

Comment: Reame new layout name to "default" to start automaticaly

Comment: 6. Set a custom initial command for each window. =) http://askubuntu.com/questions/349385/how-to-start-terminator-with-a-custom-command-per-window

Comment: This works well for tabs and windows, but for some reason 'directory' and 'command' properties in config file don't function properly. At the very least I want Terminator to launch in a specific folder. --working-directory flag works as expected, but it will not allow me to specify a dir of my choice to every tab in my custom layout.

Comment: Any way to save the layout from a shell command?

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me. The current accepted answer does not work.

Comment: In my case, after just installing Terminator for the first time, when clicking "Add" in the Layouts tab, nothing happens.  Not sure why...

Comment: It does not work. This is even commented in the documentation. The documentation recommends creating the profile first, saving it, closing and opening it again and then add the custom commands without saving (?)
Editing the config also works, which is why I found this question because I couldn't recall the path, LOL

Comment: Needs an option to set default to user-preferred layout.

Answer (score 24):

After saving your layout (as per **mhnagaoka**'s answer), you can make your changes used by default by editing the config file.

Edit the `~/.config/terminator/config` file and look for where it says `[layouts]`. It should look something like this:

```
[layouts]
  [[default]]
    # ..default layout
  [[yourLayout]]
    # ..your custom layout
```

Rename `[[yourLayout]]` to `[[default]]` and remove/rename the previous default layout. Now, when Terminator starts without any parameters, it will load your **custom `default` layout**!

Comment: This answer suited me best because it doesn't rely on using any mouse interaction.

Answer (score 20):

I use the method **mhnagaoka** suggested, but I made it usable from the launcher in Unity.
I also had an issue with plain `terminator -l my_default` command, 
so specify these additional flags

- **-b** for borderless and
- **-m** for maximized.

The final Command is `terminator -m -b -l my_default`.

Now you need to modify terminator.desktop entry for Unity.

Go to your application folder, in my case it was `/usr/share/applications`.
You need to have root permissions to edit with your text editor `terminator.desktop`.

In my case it was, `sudo vim terminator.desktop`.

Replace the **Exec** argument with your Command.

Now you can add the entry to your Unity Launcher, and it should always open your custom layout on the start.

Comment: not working in my 14.04 :( it just shows the same single terminal terminator window

Comment: You have to add `; bash` or `; zsh` (depending on your shell) after each command in your layout. Then it works fine and opens all windows.

Answer (score 9):

After setting up your layout, right-click on any terminal background and choose **Preferences → Layouts** tab and click on **Add** button. When prompted for the name type "default" and hit **Enter**.

Note: This may be a glitch but it's a useful glitch for me!

Comment: Nice solution and its working perfectly. Thanks :-)

Comment: To everyone looking for the answer. This is the best and the easiest answer.

Comment: This is awesome.

Comment: This does not work anymore..

Comment: It works on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Answer (score 8):

To open a previously saved layout, open the Terminator Layout Launcher by pressing ALT-L. There, click on the layout you need, and press launch.

Answer (score 7):

It's very simple. No need to edit the configuration file.

Just create your custom layout and Right Click->Preference->Layout->default and Press the save button. Now our configuration is saved as the default configuration. From next launch of the terminator, we will get the custom layout at the startup itself.

Comment: Found this to be the easiest solution of them all here.
Firstly, positioning and creating set of windows and groups you want. Then saving custom layout and then re-opening the terminator did the trick!
Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Just as an anecdote, even after configuring custom layout 're-use profile for newer terminals' has to be checked otherwise the new terminal again opens in default profile.
[image]