# How do I get Terminator child windows to start at a certain size?

Tags: terminator, layout

Thanks to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/158159/how-do-i-get-terminator-to-start-up-with-my-custom-layout), I've managed to get Terminator to open at a particular size, with the right configuration of child windows.

However, they don't open at the size/position that they were in when I saved the layout.

Edited To Add: The layout portion of my config file contains lines like below. The first part (`[[[child0]]]`) is the main window, while `[[[child1]]]` is one of its children (as indicated by the `parent = child0` line). Changing the number in the line that reads `position = 1237` has no effect that I can see.

```
[[MyLayout]]
  [[[child0]]]
    position = 27:29
    type = Window
    order = 0
    parent = ""
    size = 1052, 1853
  [[[child1]]]
    position = 1237
    type = VPaned
    order = 0
    parent = child0
```

I've tried adjusting the `position = NNN` lines in the childN sections, but to no avail.

(As a bonus question, if they aren't there to set the size of those windows, what are those `position` lines supposed to do, anyway?)

Comment: I'm not sure what values the `position` and `size` settings take, but for me, they look like: 

    `position = 0:27
    size = 1920, 478`
for a window that stretches the full width of my 1920x1080 monitor, and is located at the top right-corner (oddly, even though I've given 1920 as the width, it shrinks to fit the space left by Unity's fat Launcher).

Comment: Yes, that's what they look like for the main window, but for the child windows, I just get a line like:  

`position = 600`.  

It doesn't seem to do anything, though.