# How do I get terminator to start up with my custom layout with custom commands?

Tags: terminator, layout

Similar to this one: [How do I get Terminator to start up with my custom layout?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/158159/how-do-i-get-terminator-to-start-up-with-my-custom-layout)

I can get my terminator 0.97 that I installed from ubuntu 14.04 repositories to start up with custom layout properly, if I don't add any custom commands to any terminals. If I add a custom command to any one or more terminals, it will only start up showing the terminals that didn't have any custom commands added to them.

If I add `sleep 5;ls` as a command to one of four terminals in the layout for example, it will show 4 terminal windows for 5 seconds, and after 5 seconds one of them will disappear.

```
v@v-MS-7599:~/.config/terminator$ cat config
[global_config]
  enabled_plugins = CustomCommandsMenu, LaunchpadCodeURLHandler, APTURLHandler, LaunchpadBugURLHandler
  suppress_multiple_term_dialog = True
[keybindings]
[profiles]
  [[default]]
    use_system_font = False
    autoclean_groups = False
    background_darkness = 0.91
    scrollback_lines = 2000
    background_type = transparent
    background_image = None
    show_titlebar = False
    font = Monospace 16
  [[new]]
    background_image = None
[layouts]
  [[default]]
    [[[child1]]]
      type = Terminal
      parent = window0
      profile = default
      command = ""
    [[[window0]]]
      type = Window
      parent = ""
  [[test2]]
    [[[child0]]]
      position = 426:218
      type = Window
      order = 0
      parent = ""
      size = 1042, 643
    [[[child1]]]
      position = 321
      type = VPaned
      order = 0
      parent = child0
    [[[child2]]]
      position = 521
      type = HPaned
      order = 0
      parent = child1
    [[[child5]]]
      position = 521
      type = HPaned
      order = 1
      parent = child1
    [[[terminal3]]]
      profile = default
      type = Terminal
      order = 0
      parent = child2
      command = ""
    [[[terminal4]]]
      profile = default
      type = Terminal
      order = 1
      parent = child2
      command = ""
    [[[terminal7]]]
      profile = default
      type = Terminal
      order = 1
      parent = child5
      command = sleep 5; df -h
    [[[terminal6]]]
      profile = new
      type = Terminal
      order = 0
      parent = child5
      command = ""
[plugins]
  [[CustomCommandsMenu]]
    [[[/window 6]]]
      command = /window 6
      enabled = True
      name = /window 6
    [[[/window 7]]]
      command = /window 7
      enabled = True
      name = /window 7
    [[[/window 5]]]
      command = /window 5
      enabled = True
      name = /window 5
    [[[/window next]]]
      command = /window next
      enabled = True
      name = /window next
    [[[/window previous]]]
      command = /window previous
      enabled = True
      name = /window previous
    [[[/window 11]]]
      command = /window 11
      enabled = True
      name = /window 11
    [[[/window 8]]]
      command = /window 8
      enabled = True
      name = /window 8
    [[[/window 9]]]
      command = /window 9
      enabled = True
      name = /window 9
    [[[/window 10]]]
      command = /window 10
      enabled = True
      name = /window 10
    [[[alt+4]]]
      command = /window 4
      enabled = True
      name = alt+4
    [[[/window 12]]]
      command = /window 12
      enabled = True
      name = /window 12
    [[[alt+1]]]
      command = /window 1
      enabled = True
      name = alt+1
    [[[alt+1 ei]]]
      command = "xte 'keydown Alt_L' 'key 1' 'keyup Alt_L'"
      enabled = False
      name = alt+1 ei
    [[[alt+3]]]
      command = /window 3
      enabled = True
      name = alt+3
    [[[alt+2]]]
      command = /window 2
      enabled = True
      name = alt+2
```

Here  http://pastebin.com/UTmhiBGH is a log file when this type of layout is run with -d flag. I'm not sure if I used exactly the above config. It is possible that the command or another similar command was on another terminal when this was run, but the result is always similar.

Also I have placed the LayoutManager.py plugin to the /usr/share/terminator/terminatorlib/plugins but that doesn't seem to work either, giving `PluginRegistry::load_plugins: Importing plugin LayoutManager.py failed: invalid syntax (LayoutManager.py, line 5) error.` However this custom command problem was there to begin with.

Answer (score 4):

When you run a custom command and it exits, the terminal is closed because the command has finished. For your custom commands use a seperate Profile. In that profile in the Command tab you need to change the "When command exits:" combo to "Hold the terminal open".