# Customizing and Automating Terminator Startup

Tags: command-line, bash, customization, terminator

### The First Part

Every time I boot my Laptop I **manually** open [Terminator](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Terminator/) with two tabs each having three horizontal terminals.

### My Solution To The First Part

So far I have **automated** the *First Part* using the `~/.config/terminator/config` file by creating the neccessary steps outlined in the answers of [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/158159/how-do-i-get-terminator-to-start-up-with-my-custom-layout).

---

### The Second Part

In the first tab in each of the horizontally split terminals, I **manually** execute the following steps to get a `root` shell:

```
1. sudo su -
2. Type my password
```

### My Tryouts To Solve The Second Part

I know that in `Terminator->Preferences->Layouts` it is possbile to add a `Custom Command` to each Terminal.

My problem is I can't find the correct way to write the command down in such a fashion that *Terminator* ends up being in that `root` shell.

My attempts are **manifold** and are basically **derived** from something like this, sharing the property of not resulting in the outcome I would achieve by doing it manually:

```
echo "mypassword" |  sudo -S su - ;bash
```

Please no lectures about security.

Comment: Please **don't use** excessive _formatting_ since it is **distracting** and makes your question *harder* to read.

Comment: I think it makes it easier to read actually.